# Dymola- interpolateTrajectory failed to expand

Tags: arrays, matlab, modelica, dymola

I am dealing with a problem with the interpolateTrajectory command of Dymola.
I have been trying with a lot of possibilites to make the command run, but i always receive the same error "Failed to expand InterpolateTrajectory"

--First input, I tried to insert .mat file with the matrix created with the commends **writeMatrix** or **writeTrajectory** but neither of both works.
-- Second input, I just add the .mat file matrix name {"data"}
--Third input, I include the output of a **readMatrix** command or **size** command

I tried all the possibilities but i run out of ideas as i do not clearly understand the output of InterpolateTrajectory command.

Kind Regards

ichubi

I need to create a matrix and interpolate it. It has 10 rows and the other matrix has 15 rows and it is the output of a simulation

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to interpolateTrajectory is the name of the variables - not "data".

As a simple example:

```
writeTrajectory("dsres.mat",{"Time","a","b"},[0,0,1;1,1,1;2,4,1])
interpolateTrajectory("dsres.mat",{"a"},linspace(0,2,3))
```

returns

```
[0.0, 1.0, 4.0]
```

You can use readTrajectoryNames to get those names e.g.:

```
interpolateTrajectory("dsres.mat",readTrajectoryNames("dsres.mat"),linspace(0,2,3))
```

Comment: Really Hans, the simple example it was enought to open my eyes. Not the commands are operating correctly

Comment: If you like the answer, please consider up-voting it and/or accepting it as an answer.